# Sistema de busca com Inner Join

Tags: php

Eu criei um sistema de busca.

```
Tabela Sessions
 ID - NAME - SESS - EPISODE

Tabela Movie
 ID - Movie_id, Movie_Name
```

O que eu pretendo é fazer um *select* assim:

```
SELECT id, name, sess, episode FROM sessions WHERE name LIKE '%" . $name . "%' AND user_id ='$sessionID'
```

Só que em vez de procurar o `name`, procura o `Movie_Name`. Ou seja, procura o `name` (`sessions`) e diga se é igual ao `Movie_id` (`movies`), se for mostra o `movie_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Basta especificar no INNER JOIN qual a relação entre as tabelas. No caso você quer somente os dados das tabelas onde `sessions.movie_name = movie.movie_id`.

```
SELECT movie_name 
FROM movie 
INNER JOIN sessions 
    ON sessions.movie_name = movie.movie_id 
WHERE movie_name LIKE '%" . $name . "%' 
AND user_id ='$sessionID'
```

Comment: aparece este erro, como adiciono ID e o NAME para fazer no Loop depois?
->>> 
Notice
: Undefined index: id in
C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\library.php
on line
269


Notice
: Undefined index: name in
C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\library.php
on line
269

Answer (score 0):

Visto que aparece este erro, como adiciono os campos ID e o NAME da tabela "Sessions" para fazer no Loop depois?
Eu já add depois de ON mas dá erro.

->>> Notice : Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\library.php on line 269 Notice : Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\library.php on line 269